# How to get value from the database with stored procedure and show it in MessageBox C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I have a problem and I need your help

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_MAX_ID
AS
    SELECT MAX(members_tab.mem_id) 
    FROM members_tab
```

and I but the return value in data table `I don,t know other ways`

The code:

```
public int MEM_ID()
{
    int Val = 0;
    DAL.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DAL.fetchData("GET_MAX_ID", null);
    DAL.Close();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
    }

    return Val;
}
```

I used the function like this

```
MessageBox.Show(MEM_ID().ToString());
```

but I get an error:

[image: See pics for the Error]

Comment: This means the value you're trying to read is Null in the DB. So probably your query returns nothing or that value is null in the DB.

Comment: What is the implementation of DAL.fetchData? When you debug in VisualStudio you can inspect the contents of dt. Does the table have any rows? You cannot cast DbNull to int.

Comment: Are you reading max id value to create new unique key value? It is not safe in multi user environment and could cause the same max id to be used by two application instances started by different people. MS SQL has [identity feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) that will generate unique primary key for you automatically please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your select query at stored procedure to:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(members_tab.mem_id),1) From members_tab
```